# Removing element from a list

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I know this question has been asked already, but I just want to ask about my specific implementation. I'm writing this function just to practice Prolog and better understand Prolog. Here's what I have:

```
del(Ele, [H], [H]) :- Ele \= H.
del(Ele, [H|T], [H|New]) :-
    Ele \= H,
    del(Ele, T, [New]).
```

The idea is that I will add an element to a new list called `New` if the element I want to delete is not equal to `H`. From what I understand, my code isn't working because my code stops when I reach an element where `Ele \= H`. Any ideas how to fix this?

For example, `del(5, [3,4,5,6,7], X)` will return false.

Also, are there any better solutions? It seems like a bad solution to keep adding every element in a list to a new list, since this would be slow for a large list. I'd rather just keep the elements currently in the list, find element(s) that match `Ele`, remove that element, and then return the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have described **some** cases where `del/3` should hold. But these are only cases where `Ele` is not equal/unifiable to the elements in the list. There are several things missing:

What about the empty list?

What, if `Ele` is equal to the element?

So you need to add further clauses.  (Later you might also remove some, for reasons of redundancy).

If you are using SWI, B, SICStus, or YAP, consider to use `dif/2` in place of `(\=)/2`. [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)

Here is the reason why `dif/2` is so helpful in this case. With `dif/2` you would have a pure monotonic program. And you could try it out directly:

```
?- del(5, [3,4,5,6,7], X).
   false.
```

The same problem you had. Let me just restate what the problem is: You expect that something should hold, but it does not. So the relation is too narrowly defined. If I generalize the query, I might get a better answer. Try `del(E, [3,4,5,6,7], X).` but again the same `false`. So I'll try an even more general query:

```
?- del(E, Xs, Ys).
   Xs = Ys, Ys = [_A], dif(E,_A)
;  ... .
```

Looks perfect to me! Maybe another answer:

```
?- del(E, Xs, Ys).
   Xs = Ys, Ys = [_A], dif(E,_A)
;  Xs = [_A,_B], Ys = [_A|_B], dif(E,_B), dif(E,_A)
;  ... .
```

Now we got an incorrect answer. I will instantiate it a bit to make it better readable:

```
?- del(e, [a,b], Ys).
   Ys = [a|b]
;  false.
```

This answer is clearly incorrect because `[a|b]` is not a list. And, it's probably the smallest incorrect answer...

What I want to show you by this is that you can most often locate problems **without** going through it step-by-step. Step-by-step debugging does not even work in imperative languages once you get a more complex control flow (like concurrency) ; and it does not scale at all in Prolog.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe that was the problem! I guess I'm just so used to OOP that I think if I just recursively go through the list and it `Ele` doesn't equal to `H`, then it'll skip this element and move on to the next.

Comment: @user1831442: You are too much attached to the actual execution of Prolog. That's normal, when you come from a command oriented language.

Comment: @false: but unfortunately, I have found that writing *correct* Prolog programs requires thinking about the execution model. It is admittedly not the same as programming in C, but at least I can't write even a simple predicate (like OP's example) without thinking actively about the procedural meaning of the program. I guess it eventually gets internalized so well that one doesn't have to think about it consciously any more.

Comment: @Boris: You need to start with pure monotonic programs. A single `(\=)/2` ruins monotonicity. The other point is to rely more on toplevel-queries and *not* on traces. You may look into tag [tag:failure-slice] for examples how very procedural properties like non-termination can be reasoned about in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

Let's trace:

```
?- trace, del(5, [3,4,5,6,7], X).
   Call: (7) del(5, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], _G218) ? creep
   Call: (8) 5\=3 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 5\=3 ? creep
   Call: (8) del(5, [4, 5, 6, 7], [_G344]) ? creep
   Call: (9) 5\=4 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 5\=4 ? creep
   Call: (9) del(5, [5, 6, 7], [[]]) ? creep
   Fail: (9) del(5, [5, 6, 7], [[]]) ? creep
   Fail: (8) del(5, [4, 5, 6, 7], [_G344]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) del(5, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], _G218) ? creep
false.
```

So you can see your code is actually failing when it gets to the 5 because `5 \= 5` is false. Your first rule is never matched because the list has more than one item in it. The second rule recurs "correctly" after finding `5 \= 3` and `5 \= 4` but since you have no `5 = 5` case in any of your rules, the failure happens there.

Incidentally, let's see what happens when 5 does not occur in the list:

```
?- trace, del(5, [3,4,6,7], X).
   Call: (7) del(5, [3, 4, 6, 7], _G350) ? creep
   Call: (8) 5\=3 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 5\=3 ? creep
   Call: (8) del(5, [4, 6, 7], [_G473]) ? creep
   Call: (9) 5\=4 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 5\=4 ? creep
   Call: (9) del(5, [6, 7], [[]]) ? creep
   Fail: (9) del(5, [6, 7], [[]]) ? creep
   Fail: (8) del(5, [4, 6, 7], [_G473]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) del(5, [3, 4, 6, 7], _G350) ? creep
false.
```

This is why I said "correctly" before: your inductive case isn't right either. For one thing, you have `del(Ele, T, [New])` but up above you have `del(Ele, [H|T], [H|New])` so you're unwrapping the list an extra time on the right (this is why our trace has `[[]]` in it). But @false hit the larger issue which is that you simply never account for the case where you actually find what you are looking to delete. :) You also don't handle the case where the list is empty.

It is an unfortunate fact of life that traversing data structures and looking at each item is going to be O(N). Another unfortunate fact is that in functional and declarative languages (languages that lack ["assignables"](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/words-matter/)) modifying a list means copying at least part of the list. There are more efficient ways to go about this in Prolog (you could use difference lists, for instance) but they will share the same basic problem. Prolog efficiency is a rather large topic. I'd tell you to not worry about it too much up front, but it has a way of becoming your concern pretty quickly. But in this case, no, there isn't really a substantially more efficient approach using destructive updates.

Comment: Thank you! I just fixed my problem. However, I have a singleton variable since my base case is `del(Ele, [], []).` I feel like singleton variables are bad. How would I remove this warning?

Comment: They are bad. You can always get rid of the warning by replacing the singleton variable with `_`. It's also helpful because if that looks like it changes the meaning of the code (it doesn't in this case) it's a good indication that your intuition about the code is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! Daniel, you are the savior of Prolog! One last question.. I have an exam coming up, and it's pretty much going to be a test on how to write some functions for Prolog, Haskell, and Perl. I also have to know the differences of these languages (their type systems,  dynamic/static, inference engine, etc). Do you have any recommendations on what other functions I should try writing, or how I can actually understand how these languages work differently? For example, I have to know how Prolog's pattern matching differs with Haskell's and that Prolog uses unification and backtracking.

Comment: This isn't the right forum for a discussion about that (slant.co might be), but if you send me an email we can chat about it elsewhere.